# Localhost will not load under XAMPP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

I am prototyping a Wordpress site in XAMPP. Yesterday I was able log in to wp-admin. Today, when I typed http://localhost/TestSite/wp-admin, I received the following message:
Localhost refused to connect
err_connection_refused

I have tried the following:
1. Started XAMPP control panel with Admin rights
2. Used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
3. Attached Apache port number to localhost- localhost:1337, localhost:80
4. Multiple browsers: Chrome, Internet explorer
5. I have used Chrome with Proxy server setting unchecked

Nothing has worked

The only change I made to my computer between yesterday and today was to install a VPN. I have tried to access WP-Admin with the VPN activated and with the VPN not activated. No difference.

Comment: hi it's a protection by the VPN and is normal your localhost isn't really your if you are connected on VPN so close the vpn and re test ;). think when you use a VPN your browser at home it's the browser and cache from the machine VPN.. and more protocole can be too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Apache and MySQL are activated, then Try `http://localhost:8080/TestSite/wp-admin`.

Comment: Didn't work. Apache and MySQL are activated. Apache PID:2452, Ports:1337,7331. This configuration worked initially, then stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

VPN privately assigns a port number which you can't see. So ,please uninstall the VPN, restart the system. Follow the following step-
1. Start XAMPP control panel and start Apache and Mysql port.
2. Then go to http://localhost:8080/TestSite/wp-admin.
3. Now you'll see it has started and start working on it.
Enjoy!!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, after uninstalling the VPN and restarting my system and the XAMPP control panel with Admin rights, localhost would not connect. Still getting the same message:Localhost refused to connect err_connection_refused.

Comment: My configuration for Apache is PID:2452 Ports:1337,7331 This configuration initially worked then stopped working.